# Can I make git print x.y.z style tag names in a sensible order?

Tags: git, version-numbering

Consider this list of version numbers:

```
0.3.0
0.3.1
...
0.3.8
0.3.9
0.3.10
0.3.11
```

`git tag` would print them in the following order:

```
0.3.0
0.3.1
0.3.10
0.3.11
0.3.2
...
```

I there any way to make `git tag` print them in 'numeric' order as opposed to alphabetical order? Or a workaround - perhaps a program I can pipe the output through to order them how I want?

Comment: `git tag` will soon support the `--sort` option. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22635248/6309)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort git tags by version string order of form rc-X.Y.Z.W?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273531/how-to-sort-git-tags-by-version-string-order-of-form-rc-x-y-z-w) Actually, this is a slight subset because it has no prefix, but answers are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easier solution:

```
serv ~: echo -e "1.1.1\n1.3.2\n1.1.10\n1.1.2" | sort -V
1.1.1
1.1.2
1.1.10
1.3.2
```

Breakdown of the `sort` options being used here:

- -V sort by version

Comment: Not all `sort`s support `-V`.

Comment: True, but if yours does it is the superior solution since it handles any level of versioning and mixed text as well.

Comment: Even better! Good for typing on the command line as well as scripts

Comment: I usually do this as: git tag -n9 | sort -V

Answer (score 15):

```
serv ~: echo -e "1.1.1\n1.3.2\n1.1.10\n1.1.2" | sort -n -t. -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3
1.1.1
1.1.2
1.1.10
1.3.2
```

Breakdown of the `sort` options being used here:

- `-n` - sort using numerical string order (thus `10` comes after `1`)
- `-t.` - use periods as field separators
- `-k1,1` define a sort key on the first field (and only the first field)
- `-k2,2` define a sort key on the second field (and only the second field)
- `-k3,3` define a sort key on the third field (and only the third field)

Answer (score 4):

You will soon (with Git 1.9.x/2.0, Q2 2014) be able to use git only for getting the right sorted output:

See [commit b6de0c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6de0c633e60424d8d7e31a6557854683f2e4e43), from [commit 9ef176b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ef176b55c373ba087b2d84e77b5713578891927), authored by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds):

```
 --sort=<type>
```

> **Sort in a specific order**.
>   Supported type is:
>
> - "`refname`" (lexicographic order),
> - "`version:refname`" or "`v:refname`" (tag names are treated as versions).
>
> Prepend "`-`" to reverse sort order.

---

In your case:

```
 git tag -l --sort=version:refname
```

---

A few test cases:

```
git tag foo1.3 &&
git tag foo1.6 &&
git tag foo1.10
```

Here is what you would get:

```
# lexical sort
git tag -l --sort=refname "foo*"
foo1.10
foo1.3
foo1.6

# version sort
git tag -l --sort=version:refname "foo*" >actual &&
foo1.3
foo1.6
foo1.10

# reverse version sort
git tag -l --sort=-version:refname "foo*" >actual &&
foo1.10
foo1.6
foo1.3

# reverse lexical sort
git tag -l --sort=-refname "foo*" >actual &&
foo1.6
foo1.3
foo1.10
```