# How do you figure out the previous tag in such a workfow?

Tags: git, build, tags, workflow

I have a project were I use a rather uncommon tag strategy. We end up with tags being leafs so our history looks like this:

```
  0.3.0                        0.3.0
|/                               |
| 0.2.0      rather than       0.2.0
|/                               |
| 0.1.0                        0.1.0
|/                               |
```

The reason why I do this is that our tags should include the `dist` output whereas during  development we don't want to commit such files into version control. So when I run the build, the build tool automatically branches off, adds the build artifacts (`dist` folder) with a generated commit and then creates the tag there.

This workflow might look odd at first glance but so far I have found it to be quite convenient as we need to have the `dist` folder in our tags for a downstream deployment process.

Now the problem is, I want to generate release notes automatically, just the problem is, how do I figure out the previous tag in such a scenario? I'm aware of the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404796/how-to-get-the-latest-tag-name-in-current-branch-in-git) but with tags being leafs, this doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 2):

(edit: original rewarded answer down below, here's a much simpler way that tags merge bases so `git describe` can find them.

```
doit () 
{ 
    cleanup="`mktemp -t`";
    git for-each-ref refs/tags/"$1" --format='
           echo git tag -d base/%(refname:short) >> '"$cleanup"'
           git tag base/%(refname:short) $(git merge-base HEAD %(refname:short))
        ' | sh -x;
    result=`git describe --tags`;
    sh -x "$cleanup";
    rm "$cleanup"
    echo ${result#base/}
}
doit "0.*"
```

)

---

Use `latest.awk` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10903126/1290731) this way:

```
doit ()
{
        git rev-list --topo-order --first-parent --children --tags --format=%d \
        | awk -f path/to/latest.awk \
        | sed -n /$1"/,$ { /"$1"/! {p;q} }"
}
```

Testing:

> **`~/sandbox/15$ git lgdo --topo-order --tags`**
>      `* ecb363d (tag: tag4)  tag4`
>      `* cd9f402 master`
>      `| * 26aa94b (tag: tag3)  tag3`
>      `|/`
>      `* a1b6c1b master`
>      `| * 8866091`**`(tag: tag2)`**`tag2`
>      `|/`
>      `* b5d5283 master`
>      `| * 29a4e54`**`(tag: tag1)`**`tag1`
>      `|/`
>      `* cfcd7dc master`
>      `* 6120ab4 (tag: empty)`
>      **`~/sandbox/15$ doit tag2`**
>      `29a4e54debae973dfc3955d6663f14d6ade73df9  (tag: tag1)`
>      **`~/sandbox/15$`**

(edit: and

```
~/sandbox/15$ git checkout tag4
HEAD is now at ecb363d...  tag4
~/sandbox/15$ git describe --tags
tag4
~/sandbox/15$ doit `git describe --tags`
26aa94bad1e37602791c354823cb4a84ff6fc437  (tag: tag3)
~/sandbox/15$
```

)

---

(`git lgdo` being an alias for `git log --graph --decorate --oneline`, and the "master"s in there being commit-message artifacts of a make-me-some-commits helper)

Comment: I would still recommend keeping a proper structure (tag on the main branch in one repo, and release branches in another as in my answer. But your approach seems to precisely answer the OP's question, so +1.

Comment: Looks good, just a lot of vodoo for this kind of thing. I think I'll just keep what I'm using currently and wait until our deployment process will be a bit smarter so that I can do the proper fix with tags being back on the master branch. But yep, it answers the question so I think you should deserve the bounty ;-)

Comment: Thanks, and yep, that's some rigmarole right there.  I see the value in your tag structure, being able to fetch the full-media distribution for the tag you want and automatically get just the source history for the rest isn't something to sneeze at.  ... heh.  Lemme edit in a much simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

You need a different approach, with **multiple repos** (after all, Git is a *distributed* VCS):

- one as you describe
- one with **release tags combined with release branches**:

Your release is whatever latest commit you have on the release branch created for each release:

```
0.3.0--(dist) 0.3.0-branch
  |
0.2.0--(dist) 0.2.0-branch
  |
0.1.0--(dist) 0.1.0-branch
  |
```

That allows you to:

- keep the tag on the main branch
- deduce the release notes by easily finding commits between tag (for instance, `git describe` actually works here)
- have a release branch dedicating to store your `dist` folder, but also ready for hot-fixes
- tag more commits on said release branch when those hot fixes appear (`0.1.1`, `0.1.2`, ...)

All you need to do is to create a tag on the top of the release branch, and push that tag (and branch) on a **release repo** which follows what your deployment system is expecting:

```
 0.3.0
|/
| 0.2.0
|/
| 0.1.0
|/
```

Comment: yep, I know that would be better. However, our deployment currently just monitors for tags and picks them as versions to be made available in a user visible admin area. Unfortunately the deployment system can't be told to only monitor for tags with a given naming convention . So if I would go that way then all the regular tags (or branches) without the `dist` folder would go into the admin page, too. That in turn would mean it lists a lot of version which won't work if the user tried them. I know, actually it's the deployment system that should be fixed. But I don't have access to that code.

Comment: Just to further clarify. I also can't tell it to monitor on new branches. I'm very limited with a simple listener on new tags and all tags with be handled equally then. :-/

Comment: @Christoph no problem. I have edited my answer to address the specific needs of your deployment system.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best thing I was able to come up so far:

`git tag | sort -n -t. -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 | tail -1`

The sort is just to sort them in a sane way as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091306/can-i-make-git-print-x-y-z-style-tag-names-in-a-sensible-order).

However, that doesn't really take into account where your current `HEAD` is. So if you checkout `0.2.0` and then run it you would still get `0.3.0` as the previous tag which is not quite correct. However, that's not a big issue for my use case but I would still be interested if someone can come up with something that actually works correctly.

Comment: If you checkout `0.2.0`, then `git describe --tags` will give you `0.2.0`. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Nope, I need to figure out the previous tag from the leaf which is why  `git describe` won't work.

Comment: My answer didn't work for you? Just curious... (seems to work for me...)

Answer (score 0):

If the 'leaf' tag has only 1 commit from main branch:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%d %h %s" | grep '^ (' | grep -A2 '0.3.0' | tail -n1
```

You got the line include previous version tag like:

```
 (0.2.0) b5f4956 Commit message
```

Use awk to grab tag in () or sha1 after () to continue your job.

You man adjust `grep -A2` to `-A1` or `-B2` according you scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, when your current head is on `0.3.0`, you want to get `0.2.0`, and when on `0.2.0`, you want to get `0.1.0`, and so on. You can do this in two steps:

1. Get the current tag using `git describe --tags`
2. Get the list of tags sorted by date, the line after the current tag should be the previous tag

For example:

```
current=$(git describe --tags)
git for-each-ref --sort=-authordate refs/tags --format '%(refname)' | \
  cut -d/ -f3 | grep -A1 -F $current | tail -n 1
```

Let me know if this is still not what you're looking for.

Comment: It says `cut command not found`. I just tried to copy and paste it on the console. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Copy paste from browser window to console works just fine for me. Weird. You don't have the `cut` command? Which sounds extremely unlikely. But just in case, you can replace that `cut` command with awk instead: `awk -F/ '{print $3}'`

Comment: Mmh, then it says `awk command not found` but I have both `cut` and `awk`. They work fine as single command. I must confess I'm not a bash yoda so it could be I'm doing something stupid. But basically I just copy and pasted it in. :-/